# Как отобразить несколько ответов с одним статусом в сваггере (nest)?

Tags: nestjs, swagger

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь сформировать документацию в апи через swagger и nestsjs
В описании эндпоинта указываю несколько ответов с одним статусом, но отображается только один из них.

```
@ApiResponse({
    status: 401,
    description: 'Unauthorized',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 400,
    description: 'User not found',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Password changed',
    schema: { example: { message: 'Password changed' } },
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 400,
    description: 'Invalid operation',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 400,
    description: 'Password is too weak',
  })
```

Отображаются ответы 200, 401 и один из ответов 400.

Пытался сделать так, но все равно отображается только один вариант:

```
@ApiResponse({
    status: 400,
    schema: {
      anyOf: [
        {
          example: {
            description: 'Invalid operation',
          },
          description: 'Invalid operation',
        },
        {
          example: {
            description: 'Invalid operation22',
          },
          description: 'Invalid operation22',
        },
      ],
    },
  })
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как отобразить все возможные ответы с одним статусом ?

Comment: а так? https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/225#issuecomment-646014509

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, все равно какая-то фигня отображается (